# laravel/php getting object value from request

Tags: php, laravel

I've got basic store function in my `OffersController`:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{     
    $offer = new Offer;
    $offer->title = $request->title;
    $offer->body = $request->body;
    $offer->region = $request->region;
    $offer->user_id = auth()->user()->id; 

    $offer->save();

    $offer->specialities()->sync($request->specialities, false); 

    return response()->json([
        'created' => true
    ], 201);
}
```

my api request is calling `OffersController` store function with an object as below:

```
{ "title": "offer title", "body": "offer body", 
"specialities": { "lang": "en", "id": "eu33", "icon": "0",
"name": "speciality name 33" }, "region": "region1" }
```

this gives me an error: `Internal Server Error`

```
"message": "SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect 
integer value: 'pl' for column 'speciality_id' at row 1 (SQL: 
insert into `offer_speciality` (`offer_id`, `speciality_id`) 
values (59, en))",
```

so it seems I'm doing obvious mistake, so I correct my request:

```
$offer->specialities()->sync($request->specialities->id, false);
```

and this gives me an error:

`Internal Server Error, Trying to get property of non-object.`

What am I doing wrong here?

edit: table schemas:

```
    Schema::create('offers', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->string('region');
        $table->mediumText('body');
        $table->integer('user_id');
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::create('specialities', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::create('offer_speciality', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('offer_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('speciality_id')->unsigned();
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$request->specialities` is array, so to access the id you say `$request->specialities['id']`

Comment: this should be good solution, but when I write:
`$offer->specialities()->sync($request->specialities[0]->number, false);  ` I've got an error: `"Undefined offset: 0",`

Comment: it's $request->specialities['id'] NOT $request->specialities[0], you access all the properties of the json object just like accessing array elements, it's an associative array with object properties being keys to the array

Comment: sorry, I'm not familiar with php just converting data from js.  For me it should be simple - just take first element from the given array and execute

Comment: it's ok we all were beginners

Comment: well to convert specialities to normal array, you do `$normal_arr = reset($request->specialities)`, then to access the first element `$normal_arr[0]`

Comment: `$normal_arr = reset($request->specialities);`
   `$offer->specialities()->sync($normal_arr[0]->number, false);`
gives error: `"message": "Indirect modification of overloaded property Illuminate\\Http\\Request::$specialities has no effect",`

Comment: what `number` is?, it doesn't exist in your table or the json object

Comment: oh sorry, not `number` but `id`

Comment: well as i said before, to access the id, leave the array as is, dont "reset" it, and then you can access the id of the speciality just like this $request->specialities['id']

Comment: so the sync line would be `$offer->specialities()->sync($request->specialities['id'], false); `

Comment: gives: `"message": "Indirect modification of overloaded property Illuminate\\Http\\Request::$specialities has no effect",`

Comment: can you provide codepin link to your current code so i can modify it for you ?

Comment: oh, I don't want to modify my code, I just want to get `id` value from the object given by `$request`. This is pure php problem, not laravel model/schema/controllers etc. Just convert object `id` to `$id` :////

Comment: there was a small mistake but `$data = json_decode($request); $id = $data['specialities'][0]['id'];` is getting the id value. However this value is a string so I need to convert it to number in js or php

Comment: $int = (int)$data['specialities'][0]['id'];

Comment: you may improve your answer, maybe this will help someone in the future

Comment: i think it's correct, this is the way to access json object, but i wonder why you need to decode it, laravel does this out of the box, so the `specialities` is array, because it's decoded

Comment: thank you for this link! this is finally works I use simply: `$id= $request->input('specialities.id');` and then `$offer->specialities()->sync($id, false); `

Answer (score 1):

`specialities` is not being automatically hydrated from a database record, model binding only occurs when you setup the route accordingly.

It appears you're not using an unsigned integer for the `specialties` table primary key, given `"id": "eu33"`, is that correct?

Try using `json_decode($request->get('specialties'));` first then sync to offers.

Just taking a guess here, but also doing a query for the `specialities` record first like:

```
$offer->save();

$specialties = DB::table('specialties')->where('name', $request->get('specialties')['name'])
                                       ->first();

$offer->specialities()->sync($specialities->id, false);
```

Hard to say though without seeing your schema.

Comment: I'm very beginner on laravel. Let me see

Comment: I've got basic `offers` and `specialities` table with id's. And `offer_speciality` table with `offer_id` and `speciality_id` columns. This code works fine previously, but I had to modify my `speciality` into an array of objects with an `id` inside each object. My id is now `eu33` but I can convert it into digit only id. Hope this explained something

Comment: I tried: 
`$offer->specialities()->sync(json_decode($request->get('specialties'))->id, false); ` with no luck

Comment: If you can post your table schemas it would probably help get to the answer.

Comment: why? I just want to get the `id` value :)

Comment: Try the `DB` example in my answer, I updated it to use specialties name.

Comment: I don't think this is the best way. I just want to get `id` from my object :/ My function works fine and I don't want to change it.

Comment: I'm not seeing how it would work. The id is a string in the request, `eu33`, and your primary key for specialties is defined as an integer in the schema you posted. There's no way that would work in a SQL query.

Comment: I cannot base my DB queries on `name` - because it would be different on the same `id` in other languages

Comment: That makes sense with the name. The ID is going to be problematic though, it's not clear where `eu33` is coming from, but by convention, you should always keep your `id` field as an `unsignedInteger` which represents the primary key in your database tables. Laravel/Eloquent does a lot of "automagic" work behind the scenes using the `id` column to build queries and relationships. I'd refactor your logic to get rid of the string value for `id`.

Comment: okay so I will change eu33 to 33 and this will be my id. It's not a problem

Comment: your answer turned out to be very helpful to configure my speciality relation. I followed your advice and it works as it should. Thank you!